# How do I inject an anonymous function directly into an enum

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

For Dart 2.17, we can use constructors in enum similarly to how we do with classes.

I am trying to insert an anonymous function inside of an enum directly.

here is code that works but doesn't do exactly what I'd like it to do.

```
int _add(int a, int b) => a + b;
int _sub(int a, int b) => a - b;
int _mul(int a, int b) => a * b;
double _div(int a, int b) => a / b;

enum MyEnum {
  addition(_add),
  subtract(_sub),
  multiplication(_mul),
  division(_div);

  final Function fx;

  const MyEnum(this.fx);
}

void main() {
  var fun = MyEnum.addition;
  print(fun.fx(1, 2));
  fun = MyEnum.subtract;
  print(fun.fx(1, 2));
  fun = MyEnum.multiplication;
  print(fun.fx(1, 2));
  fun = MyEnum.division;
  print(fun.fx(1, 2));
}
```

Instead of making a function somewhere else in the code, as the _add, _sub, _mul, _div, I would like to directly insert an anonymous function into the enum, like in the following code (please note that the following code does not work).

*What I'd like to do*

```
enum MyEnum {
// I'd like to insert an anonymous function instead.
  addition((int a, int b) => _add(a, b)), 
  subtract((int a, int b) => a - b),
  multiplication(int a, int b) => a * b),
  division((int a, int b) => a / b;);

  final Function fx;

  const MyEnum(this.fx);
}
```

Is it possible? Would anyone be able to show me how to do this? I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried extensions? I'm not sure you'll be able to do everything you want (as happened to me), but they almost got the job done. Sometimes I just have to invoke the extension instead of the enum, probably when I put some static method on the extension (like calling `SexExt.staticMethod()` instead of `Sex.staticMethod`), but I find them pretty useful.

```
enum Sex { MALE, FEMALE }

extension SexExt on Sex {
  String getText() {
    switch (this) {
      case Sex.MALE:
        return "Maschio";
      case Sex.FEMALE:
        return "Femmina";
    }
  }

  String getShortText() {
    switch (this) {
      case Sex.MALE:
        return "M";
      case Sex.FEMALE:
        return "F";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One point of Dart 2.17 is that you no longer need to use extensions. The following code, which incorporates the features of Dart 2.17, is how I solved it. Though this certainly is not as elegant nor satisfying as I would have hoped it would have been in my original post.

```
enum MyEnum {
  addition(),
  subtract(),
  multiplication(),
  division();

  Function fx() {
    switch (this) {
      case addition:
        return (int a, int b) => a + b;
      case subtract:
        return (int a, int b) => a - b;
      case multiplication:
        return (int a, int b) => a * b;
      case division:
        return (int a, int b) => a / b;
      default:
        throw Exception('Unknown operation');
    }
  }

  const MyEnum();
}

void main() {
  var fun = MyEnum.addition;
  print(fun.fx()(1, 2));
  fun = MyEnum.subtract;
  print(fun.fx()(1, 2));
  fun = MyEnum.multiplication;
  print(fun.fx()(1, 2));
  fun = MyEnum.division;
  print(fun.fx()(1, 2));
}
```

Comment: I missed out the new enums feature in 2.17, thanks to you too for letting me know